# VsVim: Error: %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{getcwd()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l displayed under editor window

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

when i install the VsVim extension in Visual Studio the following error is displayed right under my editor window.

```
%{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{getcwd()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l
```

[image: Error]

How can i resolve the error?

Comment: That string looks a lot like what you would assign to Vim's `:help 'statusline'` to get a custom status line. My guess: your Visual Studio Code plugin doesn't support that feature or only supports it partially. In any case, head over to [their issue tracker](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/issues).

Comment: @romainl Thank you! I checked my vimrc via ":set vimrc?" and recognized unwanted imports using :help 'statusline'.